# PyYAML alternative constructors for standard tags

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

In the attempt of creating a loader that is capable of expanding variables, I noticed that PyYAML was not expanding the variables when I used block scalars (e.g. `>-`). So, take this example:

```
# ademo.yml
key1: foo
key2: bar $LOL bar
key3: >-
    baz $ASD baz
```

To expand the variables I did the following:

```
# yaamer.py
import re
import sys
import yaml

# I create a loder
class MyLoader(yaml.SafeLoader): pass

# Add to it an implicit resolver that matches variables
matcher = re.compile(r".*\$[A-Z].*")
MyLoader.add_implicit_resolver("!path", matcher, None)

# Add a constructor that would replaces the variable
def cons(loader, node):
    print("Constructing for", node)
    return "FOO"
MyLoader.add_constructor("!path", cons)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:
    print(yaml.load(inf, MyLoader))
```

When I call this, `python yaamer.py ademo.yml`, I get this output:

```
Constructing for ScalarNode(tag='!path', value='bar $LOL bar')
{'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'FOO', 'key3': 'baz $ASD baz'}
```

So, the replacement is just in key2, but not key3.

To understand what was happening I implemented a wrapper for the regex that lets me understand what's going on:

```
class Matcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.matcher = re.compile(r".*\$[A-Z].*")                                                                 
    def match(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Matching", args, kwargs)
        return self.matcher.match(*args, **kwargs)
```

and using it leads to this output:

```
Matching ('key1',) {}
Matching ('foo',) {}
Matching ('key2',) {}
Matching ('bar $LOL bar',) {}
Matching ('key3',) {}
Constructing for ScalarNode(tag='!path', value='bar $LOL bar')
{'key1': 'foo', 'key2': 'FOO', 'key3': 'baz $ASD baz'}
```

There is no trace of the block scalar in the match! So, apparently, this matcher is never used for parsing `>-` blocks.

So I investigated and found out that there are some [pre-defined tags](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), such as `!!str` or `!!map`. I though that, since `>-` is a special syntax, it would be automatically matched to one of those tags.

So I proceeded installing custom constructors for all the tags, to see if any of those was called:

```
def make_cons(name):
    def _cons(loader, node):
        print("Constructor for", name)
        return node.value
    return _cons

MyLoader.add_constructor("!!str", make_cons('!!str'))
MyLoader.add_constructor("!!int", make_cons('!!int'))
```

But they are **never** called! What is going on?? If I had to install custom constructors for pre-existing YAML tags, how would I do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implicit resolver can only match plain scalars, not quoted. Quoted means, single or double quoted, or a literal or folded block scalar. So your `key3` is a folded block scalar and therefor not considered for matching.

You can explicitly add the `!path` tag to it in the YAML source, then your custom constructor will be called.

See the [PyYAML Documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and look for the words 'implicit' and 'plain'.

To add constructors for the standard tags, you need to use the full name. `!!str` is just a shorthand for `tag:yaml.org,2002:str`:

```
yaml.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', my_constructor)
```

Comment: Thank you. So, if `!!str` is a shorthand but cannot be used there... Is it a shorthand limited to documentation? Or has it a role in the API?

Comment: It is a shorthand which you can use inside of a YAML document. maybe my [article about YAML schemas](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/01/introduction-to-yaml-schemas-and-tags.html) explains it. A YAML processor turns it into the long version when parsing. You can define your own shorthands via the `%TAG` directive, but the `!!` is the default one